# How to automate generating XML instances from XSD files, using Eclipse MDT XSD project?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, schema

I am working in a project where we create XSD schemas, and would like to generate sample xml instances for testing purposes.
In eclipse, there is an XSD editor that has the option Generate > XML which does it by a click of a button.
But I would like to convert this mouse click to a Builder, Maven or Ant task.
Any ideas of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to [write your own ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) and make use of a java library to convert a schema to xml. For example:

- Sun's XML Instance Generator (xmlgen.zip) which is part of [Sun's Multi-Schema XML Validator(MSV)](https://msv.dev.java.net/)
- [XML-XIG](http://xml-xig.sourceforge.net/)

By the way, I don't see why you want to generate test xml files as part of your build process. Shouldn't test resources be kept static instead of being regenerated every time?

Comment: Thanks - i am investigating the XML gen that you suggested - and can run it with an ant task. 
I was just wondering if it is possible to get a hook to the underlying generator in the Eclipse MDT XSD project.
Why I want to regenerate the test ressources? Well the schemas keep changing - its a BIG project - and I want to have unit tests (based on xpath) that make sure they are still consistent, and live up to companys standards.
Agata